# change color of text without border color changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that includes css of a box/border around it. I want to be able to change the color of the text (when hovered over) without the color of the border changing. I am trying to figure out a way to do it within jQuery but I have had no luck finding anything/figuring it out.

Here is some code that I have thus far. thanks.

```js
$('#container').hover(function() {
    $(this).css('color', 'blue');
  },
  function() {
    $(this).css('color', 'black');
  });
```

```css
body {
  /* background-color: #000000; */
}
#container {
  background: #eeeeee;
  width: 330px;
  height: 220px;
  /* margin-top: 350px; */
  /* margin-left: 700px; */
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-top: 5px solid #000000;
  border-top-left-radius: .5em;
  border-top-right-radius: .5em;
  opacity: .7;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 4;
  position: fixed;
  box-shadow: 8px 8px 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">here is some text where I want the color of the text to change when hovered over but not the border around the text as well</div>
```

Comment: Changing the color of the text shouldn't have any effect on the border. What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: As Barmar mentioned, it's not the border that is the problem. Your box-shadow has no defined color, so it inherits from color. Try defining a color for your box-shadow and it will work: box-shadow: 8px 8px 2px #000;

Comment: `box-shadow`: "If not specified, the color used depends on the browser - it is usually the value of the color property, but note that Safari currently paints a transparent shadow in this case." -- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)

Answer (score 3):

Do not use jQuery for that. Simply add the following `CSS`:

```
#container:hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can simple do that with css

```
#container:hover {
 color: blue;
}
```

But for learning purposes the reason your "Border" is changing colors is because it is not a border it is a box-shadow and you have not sett the color of the box shadow. Doing the code below will fix your problem as well if you want to continue using jQuery for learning purposes.

```
  box-shadow: 8px 8px 2px black;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your css:

```
 box-shadow: 8px 8px 2px red;
```